# SQLite Blob insertion c++

Tags: c++, sqlite

After visiting dozens of websites containing info about SQLite I still cannot find a solution to fix an error while binding a blob. Here is the table decleration:

```
CREATE TABLE ONE ( 
ID    INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
                  NOT NULL,
NAME  CHAR( 50 )  NOT NULL,
LABEL CHAR( 50 ),
GRP   CHAR( 50 ),
FILE  BLOB 
);
```

And here is the code for insertion:

```
int InsertFile(string name)
{
const char* dbname = name.c_str();
sqlite3 *database;
int rc = sqlite3_open(dbname, &database);
char *zErrMsg = 0;
unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);

ifstream file;
file.open("Sql.pdf", ios::in|ios::binary);

    if ( ! file )
{
        cout << "An error occurred opening the file" << endl;
}

int count = 0;

const void* fileptr = NULL;


fileptr = buffer;

while(file.good())
{
    char c=file.get();
    buffer[count]=c;
    count++;
}
file.close();


sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;

char* statement = "INSERT INTO ONE(     ID,    NAME,    LABEL,    GRP,    FILE ) VALUES (     NULL,    'fedfsdfss',    NULL,    NULL,  ?);";

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, statement, 0, &stmt, NULL);


rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, fileptr, sizeof(char)*count, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


const char* result = sqlite3_errmsg(database);


rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);

result = sqlite3_errmsg(database);

sqlite3_close(database);


free(buffer);

fileptr=NULL;

return 0;
```

}
EDIT: Pasted full function, the amount of characters im trying to insert is about 350K.

The result from binb_blob is always 21, error code contains nothing. buffer contains binary file data, which most probably isn't too big hence the error code. Any hints would be  apprieciated.

Comment: `fileptr = &buffer;` for one.

Comment: It's also possible that `count` is bogus -- we don't see how that is set.

Comment: count is the amount of characters in the buffer, and whats wrong with fileptr? Placing the buffer itself doesnt change anything imo

Comment: Why do you take the address of the address of the buffer??

Comment: (As an experiment, replace "fileptr" with "NULL" in the bind statement.  I'm betting it will run without error.)  (At least assuming that the DB was successfully opened -- did you check the return code from open??)  (And did you check the return code from prepare???)

Comment: Every return code before bind returns 0, thus it's open. Actually with NULL values it doesnt go errorfree aswell (same issue). Assumed placing NULL as fileptr.

Comment: I'm using the pointer since i'm trying to stick to the official syntax: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Comment: It doesn't say `const void**`.

Comment: Is there another way to alocate more than 65536 bytes in an array than by using malloc? char ptr seems to be the only choice to me

Comment: You also have an unnecessary `;` in the SQL statement, but I don't think that's necessarily causing a problem.

Comment: I never said there's anything wrong with the malloc.   It's `fileptr = &buffer;` that's wrong.

Comment: The semicolon is also present in the statement used to create a table, doesn't seem troublesome.

Comment: well i changed it to fileptr = buffer which didn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Well, the above is obviously not your real code, so hard to say what you mucked up.  (FWIW, 21 is "misuse" -- a bit of a catch-all for bad parameters, using statements in the wrong sequence, etc.)

Comment: You say above you pasted the full function, but obviously not, since there's no code for checking the return codes from open and prepare.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code has too many errors to count.

Try something like this:

```
int InsertFile(const string& db_name)
{
    ifstream file("Sql.pdf", ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!file) {
        cerr << "An error occurred opening the file\n";
        return 12345;
    }
    file.seekg(0, ifstream::end);
    streampos size = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0);

    char* buffer = new char[size];
    file.read(buffer, size);

    sqlite3 *db = NULL;
    int rc = sqlite3_open_v2(db_name.c_str(), &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL);
    if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
        cerr << "db open failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
    } else {
        sqlite3_stmt *stmt = NULL;
        rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db,
                                "INSERT INTO ONE(ID, NAME, LABEL, GRP, FILE)"
                                " VALUES(NULL, 'fedfsdfss', NULL, NULL, ?)",
                                -1, &stmt, NULL);
        if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
            cerr << "prepare failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
        } else {
            // SQLITE_STATIC because the statement is finalized
            // before the buffer is freed:
            rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, 1, buffer, size, SQLITE_STATIC);
            if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
                cerr << "bind failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            } else {
                rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
                if (rc != SQLITE_DONE)
                    cerr << "execution failed: " << sqlite3_errmsg(db) << endl;
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(db);

    delete[] buffer;
}
```